# How usleep unloads the CPU?

Tags: php

Can anyone explain me how **usleep** or **sleep** helps to unload the CPU.
I have written sample code as below.

```
while (1) // check if the data file has been modified 
{
  usleep(10000); // sleep 10ms to unload the CPU**
  clearstatcache();
  $currentmodif = filemtime($filename);
}
```

Comment: On what condition do you exit that loop?

Comment: It is not 'unloading'. Sleep simply puts your process to sleep and allows some other process to run and thus, your process doesn't take 100% of CPU's time slice (duration depends on various factors). This is how multitasking is achieved.

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep

Answer (score 2):

If you run `usleep()` the CPU will not spend time waiting around.
Instead it will set a timer and use the extra time on other threads/programs.

If you write code that does a lot of work to burn away the CPU time, the CPU will be working hard at that, ignoring other tasks, because it thinks it is doing useful work.
If you use `usleep` the CPU (actually the OS) knows there is nothing useful to be done and will prioritize other work.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that you have to wait 8 hours for some event.
You have 2 choices:

- look at watches each second
- set alarm after 8 hours and go to sleep or do something else

So `sleep()` and `usleep()` is second variant.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing that use this: http://www.php.net/inotify

Be sure to use `stream_set_blocking()` to turn on blocking mode - that way you won't use any cpu at all while waiting.